# Returning single row from pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables

```
Create table posts (
    post_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_title Varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 Primary Key (post_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Create table publishers (
    publisher_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    publisher_name Varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 Primary Key (publisher_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Create table publisher_terms (
    term_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    publisher_id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 Primary Key (term_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I want to retrieve all posts with just one publisher. I have tried following inner query but my I am getting unknown column error.

```
select P.post_title FROM posts P, (SELECT PB.publisher_id FROM publisher_terms PB WHERE P.post_id=PB.post_id LIMIT 1) PT;
```

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: Unknown column 'P.post_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the post with publisher using this post. Because of the post titles can be not unique I include `post_id` in the result.

```
select P.post_id, P.post_title, MAX(PS.publisher_name) publisher_name
FROM publisher_terms T
   JOIN posts P
      ON T.post_id = P.post_id
   JOIN publishers PS
      ON T.publisher_id = PS.publisher_id
GROUP BY P.post_id, P.post_title
```

Comment: I want to retrieve all posts. I do not have publisher id or name

Comment: All posts from all publishers? From your post `I want to retrieve all posts with just one publisher.`

Comment: Sorry, if my question is unclear. I want to retrieve all posts and their publishers. Limiting publishers to one per post. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: What does it mean `Limiting publishers to one per post.`? One post can have many publishers?

Comment: Yes, as this table suggests `publisher_terms` one post may have one or more publishers

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve the underlying "Why is this not working?" but can this be re-written as a Join with a Count aggregate over publisher_terms and then use a Having clause in the group by to limit it?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html has more explicit instructions, but it would be something like:

```
SELECT P.post_title, count(publisher_id) as c
  FROM posts P
    JOIN publisher_terms PT
  ON P.post_id = PT.post_id
GROUP BY P.post_title
HAVING c = 1
```